# File copied to Debug folder is automatically deleted when the C# program launches

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, dll, dllimport

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to build a WPF program. There is a DLL compiled from *C* that I use *DllImport* to call. The Dll is added in the project and marked as

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

When the project solution is built the dll is copied to Debug folder with the .exe generated by Visual Studio successfully. However, when i run it, either by double click the generated .exe from File Explorer or "Run" in the VS debugger, the dll suddenly gets deleted by itself.

Why?

Comment: I find that not only DLL but even a simple abc.txt added as Content will also be removed automatically upon program launches.

Answer (score 1):

If it does this when running from File Explorer, then either

- Your anti-virus program is deleting the dll when you try to access
  it

or

- There must be code in your program to delete files in the
     current directory.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries I've found some pattern which can be also a workaround. Assume we have 3 projects, A, B and C.

1. A depends on B; B depends on C - problem exists
2. A depends on B and C; B depends on C - problem disappears

Maybe it'd help someone to track the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this, and successfully fixed.

Two things you need to check:

1. In the project App.xaml, you need to make sure

   - For Application x:Class="..." set to YourWpfProject.App
   - For StartupUri="..." set to the folder your View(MainWindow.xaml) belongs to.
2. In the beginning of your View(MainWindow.xaml) file, you need to make sure

   - For Windows x:class="..." set to exact namespace your xaml file(View) belongs to. Remember to check clearly if you put your views or viewmodels into a folder under this project.

Now, try your "F5".